# Reference SSAS Parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I have a parameter in my SSRS report called Year. My datasource is SSAS. When I reference the parameter in a text field I get..

[Dim Date].[Year].&[2012]

How do I extract out the 2012 from this?

Answer (score 3):

Change your reference expression to use .Label, not .Value.